# Retrieving CGI Auth_User variable whith IIS Windows Authentication Enabled, ColdFusion 2018, and Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Tags: coldfusion, cgi, windows-authentication, windows-server, coldfusion-2018

I'm attempting to retrieve CGI variable Auth_User when a user has supplied their credentials after logging into their local computers using Active Directory.

I have ensured that Microsoft Authentication and Anonymous Authentication is Enabled at the Web Server Level and the Site Level in IIS.

I put the following code in the web.config which returned a 500 error.

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
    <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

It states the Server_Protocol is HTTP/1.1, Server Software Miscrosoft-IIS/7.5.

Does anyone have any further suggestions?

Comment: You have to disable anonymous authentication. With that enabled it allows no credentials. You should have only Windows Auth enabled. This will force the browser to send the authenticated user's id (or prompt for it).